# mysql dump file corrupted

Tags: linux, mysql

I've been using the following command to dump my databases:

`$ mysqldump -uuser -ppass --all-databases | gzip > all-db.sql.gz`

A full dump of the database is around **130 Gb**, and takes about 10 hours to complete.
After finishing a recent dump, I found that the gzip'ed file is corrupted:

`$ gunzip < all-db.sql.gz > /dev/null
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error`

AFAIK, the file has not been modified, nor has the `mysqldump ... | gzip` command been interrupted.

What's going on here? (Have you had similar issues?) I suspect disk corruption, but am unable to run `fsck` at the moment. Are there any issues (other than filesystem corruption) that might cause this file to become corrupted? Could `gzip` be to blame?

I realize this question is somewhat generic, but I cannot fathom a more specific problem to track down. Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

File corruption comes in many flavors or situations....I think you are right concerning possible disk corruption....if this is true, you should IMMEDIATELY restart your system, and force a full fsck so as to hopefully repair the damage to make a backup.  Leaving things the way they are may cause other more serious damage to your disk.  I'd also be checking my system logs too!

Comment: Normally, I'd agree with you. But a restart might be just enough to render the filesystem (completely) unusable. If I can get recover my data, I'll do an `fsck` right away! (Forgive me for hoping that you are wrong.)

Comment: Then take a backup (if you can) now....then reboot.  BTW, if fsck would render a filesystem unusable it already is!

Comment: I don't mean that. Perchance the only "valid" copy of fs structures is in a driver-level cache. I'm pretty sure things like the superblock are cached in memory while the fs is mounted. Or perhaps the usual shutdown process would scrape the drive... the possibilities are all scary.

Comment: OTOH, taking a block-level backup is a really good idea. (At least it won't get any worse.)